# SSRS error message: The request failed with HTTP status 400: Bad Request

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

An admin updated the dev and test servers by adding Report Viewer 2012 for me.

I have no access to the test server, but am admin on the dev server. I can work with someone who has admin access to the test server, but I will need to know what to look for.

My SSRS reports deployed from Visual Studio 2012 were converted to Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms 11.0 from version 10.0.

These reports work just find on my dev server, but when my QA tester uses the report, the first time the page shows the error "The request failed with HTTP status 400: Bad Request."

Note that no report is loaded by default.

Once we request a report, this report shows up properly and the error message disappears.

I am trying to remove this initial error message, as it is confusing for the end user.

Does anybody have any idea?

Thanks in advance!

Below is the code as shown by developer tools.

```
<DIV id=ctl00_Body_ReportViewer1_ctl09_VisibilityState ForNonReportContentArea="true" NewContentType="Microsoft.Reporting.WebFormsClient.ReportAreaContent.Error"><INPUT name=ctl00$Body$ReportViewer1$ctl09$VisibilityState$ctl00 value=Error type=hidden> </DIV><INPUT id=ctl00_Body_ReportViewer1_ctl09_ScrollPosition name=ctl00$Body$ReportViewer1$ctl09$ScrollPosition value="0 0" type=hidden><SPAN id=ctl00_Body_ReportViewer1_ctl09_Reserved_AsyncLoadTarget></SPAN>
<DIV style="DISPLAY: none" id=ctl00_Body_ReportViewer1_ctl09_ReportControl><SPAN></SPAN><INPUT name=ctl00$Body$ReportViewer1$ctl09$ReportControl$ctl02 type=hidden><INPUT name=ctl00$Body$ReportViewer1$ctl09$ReportControl$ctl03 type=hidden><INPUT id=ctl00_Body_ReportViewer1_ctl09_ReportControl_ctl04 name=ctl00$Body$ReportViewer1$ctl09$ReportControl$ctl04 value=100 type=hidden> </DIV>
<DIV style="WIDTH: 100%; HEIGHT: 100%" id=ctl00_Body_ReportViewer1_ctl09_NonReportContent>
<DIV style="FONT-FAMILY: Verdana; FONT-SIZE: 8pt">
<UL>
<LI style="DISPLAY: inline">The request failed with HTTP status 400: Bad Request.</LI></UL></DIV></DIV>
```

This is the code in the aspx file:

```
 <asp:UpdatePanel ID="TFD_UP" runat="server">
     <ContentTemplate>
      <rsweb:ReportViewer ID="ReportViewer1" runat="server" Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="8pt"
          ProcessingMode="Remote" Height="100%" Width="100%" PromptAreaCollapsed="True"
          ShowParameterPrompts="False" ShowPromptAreaButton="False" 
           ShowBackButton="False" ShowFindControls="False" ShowPrintButton="False" 
          ShowRefreshButton="False" ShowZoomControl="False"
         ></rsweb:ReportViewer>
       <rsweb:ReportViewer runat="server"></rsweb:ReportViewer>
  <Triggers>
       <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnClick" EventName="Click" />
   </Triggers>
   </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Answer (score 1):

Long story short, upgraded a 2008 solution to 2013, deployed fine initially and then started having this on deploy of all but two reports.  Tracing the service calls in Fiddler showed what looked like garbage in the password field of the data-source.  Once I re-entered the password on each failing report's data-source the errors went away.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have access to a folder with the correct permissions (or the report item itself) and not to the directory.  Check the permissions to the directory by going to the SSRS Server directly generally:

```
http: (servername)/Reports
```

Click 'Folder Settings' and then security should come up.  You should add relevant users here if you want the root of the connection to not pop up errors.  Generally speaking SSRS can be item config set, directory of child items (which may also be more directories), or root directory set.  The main landing page generally when connecting in code to SSRS is the point shown above unless you specify in code behind or a config some other starting point.

Comment: Thanks, we can look into that but do you have any idea why upgrading to the latest version alone could cause this issue?

Comment: I am not certain of why this would happen as most times upgrades take with them the policy settings.  I just know from what you are describing it sounds like the permissions are different for the parent object.  It could be the way web forms changed handling, I am not certain.  I just know access is a common issue with SSRS no matter what the front end is making the calls.